Shared Streamlit.app URL includes NOT FOUND
Why do Whatapp and messenger add NOT FOUND next to my app?  My code includes this after imports on main python page home py I have included all the options that you see at the top of my app top right the Ellipsis thingy but didn't help.  My expected results are just to show the URL and maybe the name of the app maybe some spam from streamlit but not a not found icon.


Turned out to be the icon path... doh.  Fixed it; but, no icon shows only the apps title.
